# Log entries for files in GCP buckets downloaded via SignedUrls

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm looking to record some statistics for files downloaded from my GCP bucket using signed urls. I was hoping to do this using [Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logging), but I'm unsure if this is possible.

Reading up on [Data Access logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#data-access), I found the following which made me think it is not:

> Resources that can be accessed without logging into a Google Cloud, Google Workspace, Cloud Identity, or Drive Enterprise account don't generate audit logs. This helps protect end-user identities and information.

Has anyone been able to record file download statistics if the file was downloaded by an anonymous user using a signed url. I don't require statistics on "who" downloaded the file, only that is has been downloaded and how many times it was downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you have a bucket that potentially has signed URL downloads. If so, you could view the project's data access audit logs and confirm for yourself that they include the data you expect. See: [Viewing Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#viewing_audit_logs)